# Built-in functions in JasperStudio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I'm developing some reports in JaspesoftStudio 6.0.1 and can't find any description to built-in functions that are represented in Expression Editor. So I don't understand which parameters this functions can accept. It would be great if anyone could give me reference to the description of all built-in functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any "official" documentation of this kind.
My advice is to give a look directly to the code.

Here it is the location to check: https://sourceforge.net/p/jasperreports/code/ci/master/tree/jasperreports/demo/samples/functions/src/net/sf/jasperreports/functions/standard/

Look at the following classes that refer to the different functions presented in the expression editor:

- DateTimeFunctions.java
- LogicalFunctions.java
- MathFunctions.java
- TextFunctions.java

As you might see, some functions are working with more "generic" parameter types like `Object` or `Number` in order to be more "flexible".

P.S: you could open an enhancement request in the Jaspersoft Studio tracker, asking for showing this info somehow in the expression editor (i.e. detailed tooltip).

Answer (score -1):

There's listings of the built-in functions here, in various formats:

- http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/FunctionsReport.html
- http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/FunctionsReport.pdf

Examples are at the bottom of the page.

These are referenced from [JasperReports - Functions Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/functions/index.html#builtinFunctions)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain how this doesn't answer the question. The linked pages are too long to reproduce here.